# UIBarButtonItem not centered

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I've added a single button to the center of a toolbar using:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                          target:self
                                                                           action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                        target:nil
                                                                        action:nil];

self.toolbarItems = @[spacer, addButton, spacer];
```

But the added button is not quite centered:

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: Have you added the FlexSpace to both sides?

Comment: I have - see code (I use the same spacer twice).

Comment: I'm developing for an iOS device, not Android ;)

Comment: I really don't think anyone would care.

Comment: Boo you guys are no fun! If I noticed (which I did, immediately), others will. Plus, I find it hard to believe that over five (six) iterations of the platform, no-one would have noticed and fixed this. So I remain hopeful that I am doing something wrong and it's not a flaw in the SDK. Maybe someone else can confirm the same behavior?

Comment: Good luck with trying to get an answer. But I really do think you are mad for letting it bother you so much.

Comment: Measured the home button in the above screenshot in xScope to verify the home button itself is centered (it is).  I'd guess the '+' asset returned by the OS isn't centered within the image -- supply your own and enjoy.

Comment: @BenPackard do you have a Radar we can duplicate?

Comment: If you find this annoying (I do), never, ever check the Page Control, which is wildly off-center. (I think Marc Edwards of Bjango first pointed this out.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the same spacer twice in the array - the value may be different in each - make two spacers.

Comment: Makes no difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to think it's some sort of an iOS-wide bug. That, or they got it wrong in many places. For example, paging dots on home page aren't centered. The Notification Center's top 3 buttons (Today, All, Missed) are also a few pixels off. Plenty more like that. So this may be corrected in the next update.

For now, I'd try to force it to center (say, in viewWillAppear). Pseudo-code below, no time to test :P:

```
self.toolbarItems[1].center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
```